# Why assigning for the both list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have assigned values for variables like this. It's worked nice.

```
In [16]: var1 = var2 = 5
In [17]: var1 = 2
In [18]: var2
Out[18]: 5
In [19]: var1
Out[19]: 2
```

Same operations done with list.

```
In [20]: list1 = list2 = []
In [21]: list1.append(5)
In [22]: list1
Out[22]: [5]
In [23]: list2
Out[23]: [5]
```

Same method i initialized two lists. After insert value in `list1` but it's effect the value of `list2`. How it's happening. I wonder why it's happening like this. Anyone please explain.

Thanks

Comment: Note that these are *not* the same operations; in the first one you rebind `var1`, but in the second one you *mutate* `list1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you say `list1 = list2 = []`, list1 and list2 are *the same list object*. So when you add new elements to that object, they are there whether you access it by the name `list1` or by the name `list2`.

The answers to [this earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689312/python-two-objects-are-the-same) may be enlightening. (Perhaps this question should be marked a duplicate of that one?)

Comment: As per programming it's should be different objects right ? Is it a defect of 'Python` language or my way of coding ?

Comment: Nope, they are two names for the exact same object.

Comment: You can explicitly make a copy if you want to: e.g., `list2 = list1[:]` will make a new list with the same elements, and then modifying one will not change the other.

Comment: It's not about problem solving. I can initialize independently. But My doubt is s it a defect of 'Python` language or my way of coding ?

Comment: It's a feature of Python. *Assignment by Reference*.

Comment: Python behaves this way by design (so it's not a defect in the sense of a *bug*) and it's a pretty sensible (and common) way for a language to behave (so it's not a defect in the sense of a *design flaw*). If you write Python code on the assumption that saying `a=b` takes a copy of whatever's in `b` rather than just making `a` another name for it, then that's a defect in your way of coding because in fact assignment doesn't do that in Python.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your valuable comments.

Comment: (But *wanting* it to work a different way isn't necessarily a defect in your way of coding. There are languages in which assignment generally means copying -- for instance, C++ and MATLAB -- and those are clearly also languages in which one can get real work done. Personally, I find the Python way clearer for most purposes.)